# Is there another way to remove items from a list that a user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a name picker. I want to remove the name after it is chosen and allow the user to pick another name. So let's say I type in 6 names as the user following the prompts. Each time it goes through the loop it is choosing a new name until the 6th time. At the 6th time it repeats a name already chosen. I am using .append() and .remove(). Everything else works like it should except that part. I have watched other tutorials and I cannot use a specific range to remove items because the user inputs the list of names. Is there another way besides using .append() or .remove() to solve this problem?

```
def main():

    from random import choice 

    # Instructions on how to use the random name picker

    print("Hooray you decided to use a random name picker!\n")
    print("Please enter your list of names one name at a time pressing enter after each name.")
    names_list = []
    while True:
        resp = input('Enter a new Name or the word quit to stop ')
        if resp.lower() == 'quit':
            break
        names_list.append(resp)
    print(f"You Entered {len(names_list)} Names to include {', '.join(names_list)}" )

    
    
    # Ask user if they want to pick another name
    while len(names_list) > 0:
        answer = input("\nDo you want to pick a name? Type y or n and then press enter." + " ")
        if answer == 'y':
            group = []
            students = choice(names_list)
            print("\nSelceting a name...")
            print(f'I have selected {choice(names_list)}')
            group.append(students)
            names_list.remove(students)   
        if answer == 'n':
             print("Thanks for using the random name picker \n\n")
             input("Press the enter key to exit.")
             break
            
    while len(names_list) == 0:
          answer = input("Your list is empty." + "" "Do you want to make a new list? Type y or n and then press enter" +" ")
          if answer == 'y':
                  print("\n\n")  
                  main()
          elif answer == 'n':
             print("Thanks for using the random name picker \n\n")
             input("Press the enter key to exit.")
             break

# Where code starts
main()
```

Comment: Feel free to point me in the direction of where I should read to find this information as I know this is not a place for tutorial services. I have watched a lot of videos to learn loops and how to remove items and applied what I leaned to that section of the code.

Comment: Change `print(f'I have selected {choice(names_list)}')` to `print(f'I have selected {students}')` and run your program again. See if that helps. It appears that, currently, what you display is not what you remove from the names_list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain it in an answer instead of a comment.

This is the problem area:

```
            students = choice(names_list)
            print("\nSelceting a name...")
            print(f'I have selected {choice(names_list)}') # <-- this is the problem
            group.append(students)
            names_list.remove(students)
```

Change that block to:

```
            students = choice(names_list)
            print("\nSelecting a name...")
            print(f'I have selected {students}')
            group.append(students)
            names_list.remove(students)
```

## What's happening in your original code?

Let's say you entered A, B, ... F.

### Loop 1

When you reach `students = choice(names_list)`, let's just say that students happens to be B.

However, when you print `print(f'I have selected {choice(names_list)}')`, then `choice(names_list)` could show you A.

Then you go on to remove B from names_list.

names_list now is A, C, D, E, and F.

### Loop 2

When the loop runs again, `students = choice(names_list)` results in students being F (let's just say F was randomly chosen).

However, when you print `print(f'I have selected {choice(names_list)}')`, then `choice(names_list)` could show you A from A, C, D, E, and F.

Then, you remove F from the list.

names_list now is A, C, D, and E

### Loop 3

When the loop runs again, `students = choice(names_list)` results in students being D (let's just say D was randomly chosen).

However, when you print `print(f'I have selected {choice(names_list)}')`, then `choice(names_list)` could show you A again from A, C, D, and E.

Then, you remove D from the list.

names_list now is A, C, and E

Hopefully, now you see why you were seeing duplicate information.

---

## How does using print(f'I have selected {students}') fix the issue?

Using `print(f'I have selected {students}')`, you are displaying exactly what you are removing.

### Loop 1

`students = choice(names_list)` results in B

You print B

Then you go on to remove B from names_list.

names_list now is A, C, D, E, and F.

### Loop 2

`students = choice(names_list)` is F

You print F.

Then, you remove F from the list.

names_list now is A, C, D, and E

### Loop 3

`students = choice(names_list)` is D.

You print D.

Then, you remove D from the list.

names_list now is A, C, and E

That way, there is no more duplicate and wrong information printed.

Comment: This explanation was awesome!! I just tried it and it works! Thank you so much for your help!